# Connect-AzAccount Powershell on-prem

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, command-line-interface

I am new to Azure and I've successfully installed PowerShell on my macOS. Now I want to run get-azvm command and stop/delete a vm from on-prem (not cloud shell).

First thing I did from Terminal:
1. PWSH to launch PowerShell
2. Connect-AzAccount, browser opens to authenticate and I get an error:

Connect-AzAccount xx: Device authentication is required.
Trace ID: xx
Correlation ID: xx
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException

3. I continue with az login command. Result:
   You have logged in. Now let us find all the subscriptions to which you have access...

{
}

4. I run: get-azvm and get another error:
   get-azvm : No subscription found in the context.  Please ensure that the credentials you provided are authorized to access an Azure subscription, then run Connect-AzAccount to login.
   At line:1 char:1

Please, what am I doing wrong? Do I need to register my on-prem machine somewhere?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have a Conditional Access Policy enabled for this identity?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in above comment - you might have conditional access policies enabled on your Azure AD so you might want to check it out and confirm. 
Secondly, if that's not the case - try running commands below before you access your azure resources

```
Add-AzAccount
Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId "your_azure_subscription_id" | Select-AzSubscription
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "your_vm_resource_group_name" -Name "your_vm_name"
```

Hope it helps?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it. If no, give the response.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error from `Connect-AzAccount`, Looks your account is [MFA-enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-howitworks), please use the [authentication methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-authentication-methods) to authenticate. Or you can create a service principal, [assign a role for it in the subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal), then you can login with the service principal and use it to `Get-AzVM`, details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-2.8.0#sign-in-with-a-service-principal-).

> I continue with az login command. Result: You have logged in. Now let us find all the subscriptions to which you have access..

You should note, `Connect-AzAccount` is used to login the [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.8.0), `az login` is used to login the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest), they are different. From the output, looks you logged in successfully in Azure CLI, you could use `az account set --subscription <subscription-id>` to set the subscription which you want to get the VMs from, then use [`az vm list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-list) to list VMs.